# WATIR save and load object

Tags: ruby, yaml, selenium-chromedriver, watir

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser = Watir::Browser.start @url = query

yml = YAML.dump(browser)
File.open("watir.obj", 'w') { |file| file.write(yml) }

#object saved ok!

#BUT PROBLEM HERE 
pp browser = YAML::load_file("watir.obj")
puts browser.html


pp will return #<Watir::Browser:0x32ef165a7e2a48ce closed=true> <<< CLOSED
```

if I try to second part of script - I will get error:

```
/Users/lir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:906:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

It looks like watir cant connect to chromedriver. Yes?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to save a browser instance that can be restarted later? I don't think that Watir/Selenium have that capability.

Comment: Lets imagine I run script and this script brind me source save object and source and exit. Tomorrow. I want to rerite script and add some code to this script, I try to load session object and continue my work.

Comment: Or imagine that watir in compiled file, it run once, save content save object, next time you will run this binary it will load session and object.